# Can't create constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I can't add constraint nomsociete in class site with `uniqueConstraints{@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="name")})`

1-class Produit:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(appliesTo="produit")
  public class Produit implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

   private Long refProduit;

   @Column(name="nomsociete")
   private String nomsociete;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="produit")
  private List<Site> listSites=new ArrayList<Site>();
```

2-class site:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(appliesTo="site",uniqueConstraints
   {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="name")})


 public class Site implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long refsite;

   @Column(name="nomsociete")
   private String nomsociete;

  @JoinColumn(name = "refProduit")
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Produit produit;
```

Error:

> The attribute uniqueConstraints is undefined for the annotation type Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have this import:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;
```

But to add `uniqueConstraints` you need to replace it with the JPA equivalent:

```
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="name")})` because it is element of @Table annotation you can also refer [uniqueConstraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Table.html#uniqueConstraints())